# Return null from method with DateTime return type

Tags: methods, nullable

I'm trying to read database records using `SqliteDataReader`. Unfortunately if some dates in my db are null or empty methods such as:

- GetDateTime()
- GetString()

throw an exception of type `System.InvalidCastException`. I thought about extending `DataReader` class:

```
public static DateTime TryGetDateTime(this SQLiteDataReader rdr, int n)
{
    DateTime ? dt = new DateTime();
    try
    {
        dt = rdr.GetDateTime(n);
    }
    catch(System.InvalidCastException)
    {
        dt = null;
    }
    return dt;
}
```

This extension method cannot be compiled as `DateTime` is by default not a nullable data type. I would be grateful if you could help me overcome this problem. I'd like `TryGetDateTime()` to return `DateTime` if possible and null if exception is thrown. Are generic return types applicable in this situation?

Comment: What means 'cannot be compiled as DateTime'? What does the compiler say? Or is 'This extension method cannot be compiled as DateTime is by default not a nullable data type.' the thrown error?

Comment: return dt gets red squiggly - cannot convert null to DateTime as because it's non-nullable value type